# jQuery Cycle2 - how to have videos in div's and to pause slide when video is started?

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, jquery-cycle2

I dont to want to slide videos and/or images, I need to slide div's which may or may not, have Youtube video inside that div.

So is it possible to have div's as slides, and if inside that div is video, user can play it, but, how to pause slide during video playback?

Thanks